# Smooth scroll doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, I've been using a nice template from Bechance.com

http://baribal.be/showpage/

When I press on the "Discover more" or "Arrow down" buttons - it scrolls down nicely

Yet when I download the template - those buttons are inactive.

Their HREF tags contain a "goto" name in class, which if removed allows the anchoring to work - but without the smooth scroll.

```
<a href="#container" class="button-white goto">Discover more</a>
```

I've basically tried everything - using other scripts (like smooth scroll), copying the code from the web - nothing seems to work.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: "Copying the code from the web" what does that mean? You downloaded the stylesheets? Alternatively you could try putting http://baribal.be/showpage/ before the CSS links.

Comment: That means i've copied the code from online INDEX.html to the offline template INDEX.html - to see if there is any difference

Comment: In my broswer I did menu option File | Save Page As, and the locally saved page works just like the online page.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your main stylesheet, add this code snippet at the very top.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Hope this works out for you!

Comment: This worked for me, it solved the issue of why this particular React JS Landing Page Template wasn't smooth scrolling  https://github.com/issaafalkattan/React-Landing-Page-Template

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the code, I see you have to inlcude the scrollto.js and the main.js. In this files, you will find the necessary code.

Comment: They are both already included in the bottom of the code. Dunno why in the bottom though)